# PureScript FFI function without return value, only side-effects

Tags: ffi, purescript

How to correctly call/define the foreign function that doesn't return anything. What am I doing wrong?

Renderer.purs:

```
module Renderer where
import Prelude
import Effect (Effect)

foreign import renderMd :: String -> Effect Unit
```

Renderer.js:

```
var md = require('markdown-it')();
exports.renderMd = function(str) {
  document.body.append( md.render(str) );
}
```

Finally calling with:

```
import React.Basic.DOM as R
import React.Basic.DOM.Events (targetValue)
import React.Basic.Events as Events

R.textarea
  { onChange: Events.handler targetValue $ maybe (pure unit) renderMd
  }
```

Compiles fine, but gives:

```
Uncaught TypeError: cb(...) is not a function
```

in the definition of what's probably purescript-react-basic's [`handler`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-react-basic/2.1.0/docs/React.Basic.Events#v:handler), compiled:

```
var handler = function (v) {
    return function (cb) {
        return function ($22) {
            return cb(v($22))();
        };
    };
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the solution is to wrap the result of your FFI function in a zero-argument function:

```
var md = require('markdown-it')();
exports.renderMd = function(str) {
  return function() {
    document.body.append( md.render(str) );
  }
}
```

This chapter of the excellent book *PureScript by Example* mentiones it: https://leanpub.com/purescript/read#leanpub-auto-representing-side-effects

I have to admit, this is less than obvious, but it actually makes sense: wrapping the effectful result in a function delays its evaluation until the function is called, which is needed for controlling side-effects.

Comment: Thanks, that works! So this hasn't changed with the new effect system... not quite sure what's the difference between the `random()` and `log(str)` examples there. Why does the latter need an inner function but not the former? Probably, because `log` takes an argument.

Comment: Exactly, `log` takes a string argument, similar to your `renderMd` function, while `random` does not need an argument.

Comment: Makes sense, but unfortunately not documented at https://github.com/purescript/documentation/blob/master/guides/FFI.md.